# TypeError: list object is not callable

Tags: python, nltk

I have the following function:

```
def sample_handling(sample, lexicon, classification):
    featureset = []

    with open(sample, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.readlines()
        for l in contents[:hm_lines]:
            current_words = word_tokenize(l.lower())
            current_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in current_words]
            features = np.zeros(len(lexicon))
            for word in current_words():
                if word.lower() in lexicon:
                    index_value = lexicon.index(word.lower())
                    features[index_value] += 1
            features = list(features)
            featureset.append([features, classification])

    return featureset
```

When I run the code, it gives me the following error:

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Is there any overshadowing going on here? I followed many threads on SO dealing with this error but could not solve my problem.

This is my full code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import numpy as np
import random
import pickle
from collections import Counter

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
hm_lines = 10000000

def create_lexicon(pos, neg):
    lexicon = []
    for fi in  [pos, neg]:
        with open(fi, 'r') as f:
            contents = f.readlines()
            for l in contents[:hm_lines]:
                all_words = word_tokenize(l.lower())
                lexicon += list(all_words)
    lexicon = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in lexicon]
    w_counts = Counter(lexicon)
    #w_counts = {'the': 52521, 'and': 25242}

    l2 = []
    for w in w_counts:
        if 1000 > w_counts[w] > 50:
            l2.append(w)

    print(l2)
    return l2

def sample_handling(sample, lexicon, classification):
    featureset = []

    with open(sample, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.readlines()
        for l in contents[:hm_lines]:
            current_words = word_tokenize(l.lower())
            current_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(i) for i in current_words]
            features = np.zeros(len(lexicon))
            for word in current_words():
                if word.lower() in lexicon:
                    index_value = lexicon.index(word.lower())
                    features[index_value] += 1
            features = list(features)
            featureset.append([features, classification])

    return featureset

def create_feature_sets_and_lables(pos, neg, test_size = 0.1):
    lexicon = create_lexicon(pos, neg)
    features = []
    features += sample_handling('pos.txt', lexicon,[1,0])
    features += sample_handling('neg.txt', lexicon,[0,1])
    random.shuffle(features)

    features = np.array(features)

    testing_size = int(test_size * len(features))

    train_x = list(features[:,0][:-testing_size])
    train_y = list(features[:,1][:-testing_size])

    test_x = list(features[:,0][-testing_size:])
    test_y = list(features[:,1][-testing_size:])

    return train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y = create_feature_sets_and_lables('pos.txt', 'neg.txt')
    with open('sentiment_set.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump([train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y], f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been more helpful had you printed the full stack-trace. As this is a relatively simple error, the problem is easily identifiable in this case. It's this line,

```
for word in current_words():
```

You needn't *call* a list while looping it. Simply this will do,

```
for word in current_words:
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start debugging, I would run the program by using

```
python -m pdb whatever_your_file_is.py
```

This will launch a pdb debugging console. Once there, press '**c**' to run the program. After awhile, supposing the program crashes, you'll be stopped at the exact location where the error occurred.

From there, you can refer to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) or [this](http://web.stanford.edu/class/physics91si/2013/handouts/Pdb_Commands.pdf) (just Google *python pdb*) to figure out exactly what's going on in your code.

Good luck!

Comment: It crashes at the `features = list(features)` portion.

Comment: What happens if you just type `features` into the console?